# Use only letters, return true otherwise

Tags: c#

Okay so I need to test a variable for containing anything but letter; meaning no spaces are allowed, no numbers and no symbols. I thought I'd figured it out but i can't get regex to work. Here's what I have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace soro
{
    class Program
    {
        static void notOnlyString(string word)
        {
            Regex.IsMatch(word, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string var1;
            //lots of code here
            var1 = Console.ReadLine();
            if (notOnlyString(var1))
            {
                //do this if it has a number, space or symbol; anything but 
                //letters
            }
            //more code
         }
    }
```

Comment: So what do you know about variable types (such as booleans) and return values? Looks like you could use a good C# book or tutorial.

Comment: The compiler is telling you what the problem is.  Read the error message.

Comment: The *regex* isn´t the problem, it´s the signature of the method `notOnlyString` causing the problem. It has void as return-type meaning it shouldn´t return *anything*. What you want instead is returning a boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it using

```
bool result = word.All(Char.IsLetter);
```

if you need Digits use it

```
bool result = word.All(Char.IsLetterOrDigit);
```

Comment: this seemed to work, though being new it says not all code paths return a value and im not quite sure what its saying
------------------------------------------------------------

  static bool onlyString(string word)
        {
            bool result = word.All(Char.IsLetter);
        }

also new to stack exchange

Comment: you should return result, static bool onlyString(string word) { bool result = word.All(Char.IsLetter); return result; }

Answer (score 1):

Your regex looks correct. The one big wrong thing about your code is the return type of `notOnlyString`.

The naming of `notOnlyString` is bad btw. Don't use a "negative" statement as the method name. I suggest `IsOnlyLetters`.

Since you are putting a call to `IsOnlyLetters` in an if statement, you should return a `bool` value.

```
static bool notOnlyString(string word) // note that I changed "void" to "bool"
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(word, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$"); / here I added "return" to return the result of the "IsMatch" call.
}
```

Now you should change the condition in the if statement to `(!IsOnlyLetters(var1))` and everything should work.

Answer (score -1):

You should change regex syntax to:
^[a-zA-Z]*$

A nice online tool is [Regex Tester](https://regex101.com/)

Hope this helps,
Serge

Comment: Any reasons why? The only difference in your example is the matching of 0-n letters, while he matches 1-n. But this doesn't make any difference since the whole string is matched anyway.